# Why setting absolutely positioned element's sibling as position:relative, brings it above the former?

Tags: html, css, css-position, absolute

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="c1">
    <div class="c2">
      <div class="circle">
      </div>
      <div class="c3">
        <div class="c4">    
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If we change position of `.c3` as `position:relative`, it is displayed on top of `.circle`, below the `.circle`, if we don't set `position` of `.c3`. Why does it happen?

[Link to Jsbin](http://jsbin.com/zemecihana/1/edit?html,css,output)

Edit: Clarified

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.c3` is placed after the `.circle` if the DOM so following the **tree order** `.c3` is after `.circle`.

If both are **positioned** and there is no **z-index** specified so the `.c3` will be placed above the `.circle` whatever the value of position is:

1. With relative you will have this:

```css
body {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

.c1 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
}

.c2 {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
}

.c3 {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  position: relative;
  background: blue;
}

.c4 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
}

.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #f00;
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 350px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="c1">
  <div class="c2">
    <div class="circle">
    </div>
    <div class="c3">
      <div class="c4">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

2. With absolute you will have this:

```css
body {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

.c1 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
}

.c2 {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
}

.c3 {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  position: absolute;
  background: blue;
}

.c4 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
}

.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #f00;
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 350px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="c1">
  <div class="c2">
    <div class="circle">
    </div>
    <div class="c3">
      <div class="c4">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can read [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/zindex.html):

> 3. Stacking contexts formed by positioned descendants with negative
>      z-indices (excluding 0) in z-index order (most negative first) **then**
>      **tree order.**
>
> ...
>
> 8. **All positioned**, opacity or transform descendants, in **tree order** that fall into  the following categories:
>
>    1. **All positioned descendants with 'z-index: auto' or 'z-index: 0'**, in tree order.
>         ...
> 9. Stacking contexts formed by positioned descendants with z-indices
>      greater than or equal to 1 in z-index order (smallest first) **then tree**
>      **order**.

So we first consider `z-index` and if equal or not specified we consider tree order.

---

Now if `.c3` is **not positioned** and we keep `.circle` **positioned**, the circle will go above `.c3`

```css
body {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

.c1 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
}

.c2 {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
}

.c3 {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  background: blue;
}

.c4 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
}

.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #f00;
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 350px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="c1">
  <div class="c2">
    <div class="circle">
    </div>
    <div class="c3">
      <div class="c4">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this case we can read this:

> 3. Stacking contexts formed by positioned descendants **with negative
>      z-indices (excluding 0)** in z-index order (most negative first) then
>      tree order.
> 4. For all its in-flow, non-positioned, block-level
>      descendants in tree order: If the element is a block, list-item, or
>      other block equivalent:

In the (3) we consider positioned element with negative z-index and different from 0 (the `.circle` is not this case) so we don't print it yet and we print our in-flow element `.c3` following (4). Then we will have this:

> 8. All positioned, opacity or transform descendants, in tree order that
>      fall into the following categories:
>
>    1. **All positioned descendants with 'z-index: auto' or 'z-index: 0'**, in tree order. ...

Now we print the `.circle` which explain why the circle is above the `.c3` in this case.

If you specify a **negative z-index** to the circle it will fall in the (3) and thus it will be below `.c3`.

```css
body {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

.c1 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
}

.c2 {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
}

.c3 {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  background: blue;
}

.c4 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
}

.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #f00;
  position: absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top: 200px;
  left: 350px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="c1">
  <div class="c2">
    <div class="circle">
    </div>
    <div class="c3">
      <div class="c4">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you specify a **positive z-index** to `.circle` you will make it follow the (9) instead of the (8) and it will remain above:

```css
body {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

.c1 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
}

.c2 {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
}

.c3 {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  background: blue;
}

.c4 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
}

.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #f00;
  position: absolute;
  z-index:1;
  top: 200px;
  left: 350px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="c1">
  <div class="c2">
    <div class="circle">
    </div>
    <div class="c3">
      <div class="c4">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. 

If we remove both relative and absolute, i.e. do not mention the position of `c3`, then `c3` is rendered below the circle. Why?

Comment: @q126y added explanation